# glassfish mail access

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jakarta-mail

I'm using `Glassfishv3` server and I have defined there a mail session via gui administration. How can I access the mail session via `JNDI` call from non-ejb class? What should I add in the `sun-web.xml` or `web.xml` file? Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`@Resource`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html)annotation;

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:mail/testSession")
protected Session mailSession;
```

or a lookup like:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Session session = (Session)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/mail/testSession");
```